# How can I convert value of attribute into a integer using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, average, attr

I have created a function that is supposed to find the value of attributes and output the average. Right now, this is not working. I believe it has to do with how I am selecting the attribute.

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/carbot3000/0kjLu3h0/7/

I need help identifying what I'm doing wrong. An updated fiddle would also be very helpful.

```
var total = 0,
valid_labels = 0,
average;

var reviewAverage = $('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]').attr('content');

$(reviewAverage).each(function () {
var val = parseInt(reviewAverage), 10);
if (val !== 0) {
    valid_labels += 1;
    total += val;
}
});

average = total / valid_labels;
$(".reviewRating").val(average);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet of your HTML:

```
<meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue">
```

With this line

```
var reviewAverage = $('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]').attr('content');
```

You're receiving a collection of jQuery objects from `$('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]')` and then trying to run a method built for a singular object. Furthermore, your `content` attribute is a number, so running `$(5)` isn't going to help either.

You can get all of your ratings to a regular array with `$.map` - and then run a `reduce` function:

```
var reviewRatings = $('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("content");
}).get();

var reviewAverages = reviewRatings.reduce(function(total, rating) {
    return total += parseInt(rating, 10);
}, 0) / reviewRatings.length;
```

Comment: I appreciate the in depth answer. Thanks for going over what I had originally done wrong. Now that I have done some more research, I definitely see I was going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Like tymeJV said. You try to use the "attr"-method on a collection. This want work the way you want it to. If you wanne stay a little closer to your code and just change 2 lines of your snippet, you could do this:

```js
var numItems = $('div[itemprop="reviewRating"]').length;
$('.reviewCount').html(numItems);

var total = 0,
    valid_labels = 0,
    average;
var reviewAverage = $('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]');

$(reviewAverage).each(function () {
    var val = parseInt($(this).attr('content'), 10);
    if (val !== 0) {
        valid_labels += 1;
        total += val;
    }
});

average = total / valid_labels;
alert(average);
$(".reviewRating").val(average);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Customer Reviews<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"Everybody was wonderful!! Very accommodating. You have a terrific staff at the Norwalk location. Please reward them well. I was pleasantly surprised with the attention to detail and"</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Jenelle</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"The staff (Elvis and John) who supervised our party at the Norwalk location were great. They were fun (wearing party hats during the party) and were very nice to the children, to us and to our guests. They were enthusiastic and were very accommodating and helpful. They even played air hockey with my son which made him very happy! I highly commend Elvis and John as party hosts. I also commend the staff at the front desk who were very nice and helpful as well."</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Jennifer</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="4.5" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"The two team member that helped with Emily's birthday, Elvis plus one other man (can't remember his name) were both excellent and really made a great effort to make sure Emily was having a great time"</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Emma</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="4.5" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"This is my second experience with Pump It Up. The children enjoyed themselves tremendously.Loved the experience from the children activity as well as the food."</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Carolyn</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"Great energy and cordiality towards family and guest!"</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Benny</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="4" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"The manager was very accommodating. He even helped us open the giveaways which were still in boxes. Sometimes parents just can't do everything and need to enjoy the party as well and this is where staff and managers come in to help. Kudos!"</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Patricia</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="4" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"I liked that a staff person came to my car with a cart and took everything from me to set up party room."</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Lisa</span></div></div></div><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"> <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> </div> <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"> <meta content="0.0" itemprop="worstRating"> <meta content="5.0" itemprop="bestRating"> <span class="star" style="color:gold;">★★★★★</span></div><div><span itemprop="reviewBody">"Jesse and the entire team ( i can't remember their names) and the very nice young lady at the register (she has twins). Exceptional team you have there. Please recognize them!! They made our children's birthday party experience very memorable. I left there feeling so happy. Thank you!! Please continue to train all of your new staff like you have trained them"</span> <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Submitted by: <span itemprop="name">Jenelle</span></div></div></div> 

<div class="reviewCount">

</div>

<div class="reviewRating">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful as well.